# How to read a single google sheets cell value in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, discord.js, google-sheets-api

I am trying to pull just one cell value from a google sheet using javascript and the google sheets API, and I am using the below code, but I keep getting the below error which I can't understand because I am using the spreadsheet id and range.

> throw new Error('Missing required parameters: ' + missingParams.join(', '));
> Error: Missing required parameters: spreadsheetId, range

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            keyFile: "sheets-credentials.json",
            scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
        });
const client = await auth.getClient();
const googleSheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: client });
const spreadsheetId = "asheetid";
googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get(spreadsheetId, `Sheet1!D1`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get(spreadsheetId, `Sheet1!D1`)
```

#### To:

```
googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get({spreadsheetId, range: `Sheet1!D1`});
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> Now there's no error but it just returns "[object Promise]"

From this situation, I could confirm that your script worked. If you want to retrieve the values from `googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get({spreadsheetId, range:` Sheet1!D1`});`, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script1:

```
const res = await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get({spreadsheetId, range: `Sheet1!D1`});
console.log(res.data);
```

#### Sample script2:

```
googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
  {
    spreadsheetId,
    range: `Sheet1!D1`,
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res.data);
  }
);
```

Comment: Now there's no error but it just returns "[object Promise]"

Comment: @TGercken Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `Now there's no error but it just returns "[object Promise]" `, it's yes. From this situation, I could confirm that your script worked. In order to retrieve the values from the modified script, I added 2 more scripts. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: the sample scripts return { range: 'Sheet1!B1', majorDimension: 'ROWS', values: [ [ '3' ] ] } so I see that it's pulling the number but how do I isolate the value so I can do other things with it?

Comment: @TGercken Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience, again. About `the sample scripts return { range: 'Sheet1!B1', majorDimension: 'ROWS', values: [ [ '3' ] ] } so I see that it's pulling the number but how do I isolate the value so I can do other things with it?`, in that case, how about `console.log(res.data.values[0][0]);`?

Comment: that works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @TGercken Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.